# Speeding up code by avoiding repeated evaluation of a function

Tags: functions, performance-tuning

I want to speed up my code and I have two ideas, but I don't know how I can implement them.
Here is a little part of my code, which I want to improve:

```
   R[FK_, f_] := 
      FixedPoint[
          Integrate[PDF[f, x]*x , {x, 0, id[Q[FK, #], #]}]
          *If[CDF[f, id[Q[FK, #], #]] == 0., 0.1, CDF[f,id[Q[FK, #], #]]]
          *id[Q[FK, #], #] &
     , seedR] ;
```

1) You can see that the function is evaluated `id[Q[FK, #], #]` 3 times. That is unecassary. Normaly I would use a Module structure, define a new variable `idd = id[Q[FK, #], #]`, like

```
    R2[FK_, f_] := 
      Module[{iddd}, 
      FixedPoint[ 
        iddd = id[Q[FK, #], #] &; 
        Integrate[PDF[f, x]*x , {x, 0, iddd}]
        *If[CDF[f, iddd] == 0., 0.1, CDF[f, iddd]]
        *iddd &
      ,seedR]];
```

but this does not work. Do you have any idea?

2) Probably a easy one:

```
    If[CDF[f, id[Q[FK, #], #]] == 0., 0.1, CDF[f, id[Q[FK, #], #]]]
```

This involves the funtion `CDF[f, id[Q[FK, #], #]]` two times. One time should be enough. How can I do this?

Thanks

Peter

Comment: Have you looked at [memoization](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=memoization)?

Comment: For 2), `If[# == 0., 0.1, #]&@CDF[f, id[Q[FK, #], #]]` will evaluate the CDF once and plug it into the If statement.  For 1) it looks like there might be an extra `&` (fourth line)?

Comment: Thanks for 2). It works.

For 1) I produces a minimal example:
The result is 2 for the working example:

`R[seedR_] := 
     FixedPoint[
     Integrate[Sqrt[#], {x, 0, 2}] &, seedR]`

But if I add another line it does not work anymore:

`R[seedR_] :=  FixedPoint[idd = #  &;  Integrate[Sqrt[idd], {x, 0, 2}] &, seedR] `

Answer (score 4):

Multiple evaluations can often be avoided by using [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/With.html). You might try something like

```
f = With[{q = Q[FK, ....]}, If[CDF[f, id[is, q, #]] == 0., 0.1, CDF[f,id[is, q, #]]]]&
```